# Apache differentiates between files and folders

Tags: apache-2.2, alias

I am running an Apache server with Aliases to "www" folders in user directories. 
If I go to "domain/~user" I get a 404, but "domain/~user/" is served correctly.
I am assuming this is because there is no file called "~user" but there is a directory.
I would like to be able to go to "~user" and have it go to the folder "~user".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enable [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html), and make sure that `DirectorySlash` directive is not disabled.